# ConTeXt: Ignore stem height

Tags: fontsize, titles, context, overlays, width

## Background

Looking to create a stylized chapter heading using the first character of the heading title.

## Problem

The stem (descender) distance of text causes the containing frame's offset to alter the location of the emphasized first letter, which is obvious from the following picture:

[image: Influential Stem]

The problematic line in the code below is this line, which was added to ensure the title text does not incur a line-break, as suggested from [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152701/2148) to a previous question:

```
\scale[maxwidth=\textwidth-(\marginwidth)]{#1}
```

When the line above is simply:

```
#1
```

Then the alignment is perfect, but when the text is too long an undesired line-break ensues.

## Code

A minimal working example:

```
\definecolor[BookColourPrimary][h=A45F62]
\definecolor[BookColourSecondary][h=9A957A]
\definespotcolor[BookColourSecondaryLightest]
  [BookColourSecondary][a=1,t=.2]
\definefont[BookFontChapterHeader][SansBoldItalic scaled 5000]
\definefont[BookStyleFontChapterCharacter][SerifItalic scaled 20000]

\defineframed[BookStyleChapterFramed][
  frame=on,
  align={left,low,nothyphenated,verytolerant},
  width=\dimexpr\textwidth-(.2\marginwidth),
  height=\dimexpr\textheight+0.25\footerheight,
]

% Extract first character
\define[1]\BookStyleChapterChar{\cldcontext{string.sub("#1",1,1)}}

% Use a nested frame to keep the overlain large letter together with
% the chapter title.
\define[1]\BookStyleChapter{%
  \BookStyleChapterFramed{%
    \inframed[align=right, frame=on]{%
      \startoverlay
        % Calculate the large letter's offset using the first character's
        % width. This allows font changes without significantly affecting
        % the distance between the emphasized first character of the
        % chapter title and the complete chapter title.
        \setbox\scratchbox\hbox{%
          \BookStyleFontChapterCharacter\BookStyleChapterChar{#1}}%
        % Shift the first character back relative to the chapter title.
        \hskip-.55\wd\scratchbox%
        \color[BookColourSecondaryLightest]{%
          \BookStyleFontChapterCharacter%
          \BookStyleChapterChar{#1}%
        }
        \vskip-1.9em
        % Ensure the text fits on the page.
        \scale[maxwidth=\textwidth-(\marginwidth)]{#1}
      \stopoverlay
    }
  }
}

% Avoid duplication...
\define[1]\BookChapterText{
  \BookColourPrimary{\BookFontChapterHeader{\BookStyleChapter{#1}}}
}

\starttext
  \BookChapterText{Test-a}
  \page
  \BookChapterText{Test-g}
\stoptext
```

## Question

How do you make ConTeXt ignore the stem height while still scaling the text to fit within the `\textwidth` margins?

Comment: Try ``\inframed[align=right, frame=on, location=height]{%``, the frame will be positioned relative to the baseline (not the depth) of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BookStyleChapterFramed needs its height adjusted:

```
height=\dimexpr\textheight-\footerheight,
```

The frame needs to be adjusted as per `phg`'s comment:

```
\inframed[align=right, frame=off, location=height]
```